# Handling routes which are not available

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I want to handle routes which are not available by displaying something like 404 not found page. How can i do that?

for example, http://jsbin.com/oZUHiXe/1/edit in this index is available so this(http://jsbin.com/oZUHiXe/1#index) doesn't throw any error. But http://jsbin.com/oZUHiXe/1#index1 throws error in console as index1 route is not available. How to handle this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define a *catchall* route using `*` and do a redirect from there:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('catchAll', { path: '*:' });
});

App.CatchAllRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
  redirect: function() {
    alert('route not existen');
    this.transitionTo('index'); 
  }
});
```

Updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eqaXojE/3/edit).

Hope it helps.